# How to make origyear be all printed in citiations when years are the same in the authoryear-comp style?

Tags: biblatex, authoryear-comp

First an MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%add parenthesis around origyear----------------------------------
\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{(#1)}%\mkbibparens
%add origyrar in citiation--------------------------------------------
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate}
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}
%add origyear and delelte the parenthesis around year in bibliorgraphy
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}
    {}
    {\printorigdate%add origyear in 
        \setunit*{\addspace}}%add space after origyear
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext{\printlabeldateextra}}}%delete parenthesis around year

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{bookot,
  location = {Place},
  publisher={ABC},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {One title},
  year    = {2001},
  origyear={1978},
}
@book{bookat,
  location = {Place},
  publisher={ABC},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Another title},
  year    = {2001},
  origyear={1976},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
some quote from \cite{bookot,bookat}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I add origyear in the citiations and bibliography. Then **how to make origyear be all printed in citiations when years are the same, i.e., make "Name (1976) 2001a,b" be "Name (1976) 2001a, (1978) 2001b"?**

Comment: @moewe Do you have any idea to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date printing code for the citation commands is spread over several places, so we have to change several different lines of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\iffieldundef{origyear}
             {}
             {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
           \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\setunit{\addcomma}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
             {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \printorigdate
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\iffieldundef{origyear}
             {}
             {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
           \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\setunit{\addcomma}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
             {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \printorigdate
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
          {\printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\iffieldundef{origyear}
          {}
          {\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
        \ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\setunit{\addcomma}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \printorigdate
           \setunit*{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\printorigdate
              \setunit*{\addspace}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
           \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printorigdate
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iflabeldateisdate
    {\printdateextra}
    {\printlabeldateextra}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bookot,
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {ABC},
  author    = {Name, Given},
  title     = {One title},
  year      = {2001},
  origyear  = {1978},
}
@book{bookat,
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {ABC},
  author    = {Name, Given},
  title     = {Another title},
  year      = {2001},
  origyear  = {1976},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
some quote from \cite{bookot,bookat,sigfridsson,worman,geer}

some quote from \parencite{bookot,bookat,sigfridsson,worman,geer}

some quote from \textcite{bookot,bookat}

some quote from \textcite{bookot}

some quote from \parencite*{bookot}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: some quote from Geer 1985; Name (1976) 2001a, (1978) 2001b; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Worman 2002]

Comment: Will it be updated in the `biblatex` package?

Comment: @M.Logic I don't think so. It is well-documented that the standard styles do basically nothing with `origdate` and friends. If you want the `origdate` shown, you need to modify the standard styles or pick a third-party style that shows it.

Comment: Why doesn't `\citeyear` print `origyear` and how to make it print that?

Comment: @M.Logic Because `\citeyear` is defined to just print the year. Nothing else. Not even the disambiguation letter in case you have two works by the same author from the same year. That's why it shouldnot be used to generate "halves of citation labels". That's what `\cite*{<entrykey>}`, `\parencite*{<entrykey>}` are for. (And for those the code also prints the `origdate`.) Why do you need `\citeyear`?